# EF4 Lazy Loading - How do I force a load?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1, lazy-loading

I have the following code:

```
    public IEnumerable<RMAInfo> GetAllRMAsByReseller(string resellerID)
    {
        using (RMAEntities context = new RMAEntities())
        {

            IEnumerable<RMAInfo> ret = from r in GetRMAInfos_Internal(context)
                                       where r.ResellerID.ToUpper().Trim() == resellerID
                                       select r;

            return ret;
        }
    }
```

When I try and access the return value, I get the expected error of:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

I know this is happening because of lazy loading, and it's trying to load now that the context has been closed (via the using going out of scope).

My question is how do I force a load before I exit the method?

I originally did it like

```
return ret.ToList<RMAInfo>();
```

This worked fine, but I'm not sure if it's the correct or best way to do it?

Comment: As a matter of style I would declare `ret` as a `List<RMAInfo>` before the `using` block, assign it using `ret = (from ...).ToList()` within the using statement, then return it after the context is disposed. It probably makes no difference but it seems clearer and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is perfectly fine and accepted.

Answer (score 2):

`query.ToList();` is the correct way to force load the results. How else would you force evaluation of linq query?

Comment: Not sure.  That's why I asked.

Comment: It can also be forced with `new List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` ... not that I would use such in this case.